# spyinformation from address bar

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to receive the information sent by the forms that use the post method. That is, for example, when I click on a button on a submit button on a site, I need to understand what it sends, like what we have in the get method. Please help. do

Comment: devtools network tab?

Comment: What does this have to do with the "address bar"? And it's not really spying if it's your client that sends the information to begin with. It's like saying that you're eavesdropping when you're listening to your own conversation. It's also completely unrelated to PHP.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried to identify and then fix the problem?

Comment: I have to send a series of forms daily. Now I want to automatically fetch the information that these forms send. For example, the form asks me to mark several fields. I want this to be done automatically